# What's the right way to bind OG tags in a dynamic Vue 3 App?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, meta-tags, vuejs3

I have a dynamic page where I need to make an API request and update the Meta Tags dynamically.

I was able to achieve that by adding API request in `App.js` and updating the head tag HTML based on the response from API.

When I share the URL on social media, the tags are not showing up as it requires some loading time.

My application has a lot of dynamic pages with many routes. However, only 1 path in routes is important for me from an SEO standpoint.

What should be my approach here to make the Meta tags show up when shared on Social Media?

Comment: did you try o use vue-meta https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-meta?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim any idea on how to use it with VueRouter in Composition API? I tried `import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'` and `Vue.use(VueMeta, { refreshOnceOnNavigation: true }) ` in my component with a ref variable `metaInfo`. But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea on how to use it in Composition API?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem in two ways.
**First**: You need to turn on SSR Server Side Rendering. In this it will render all html on server side. **Second**: If you are using vue inside Laravel Blade template then you can handle meta and og tags on Laravel Blade file side. In this way before loading vue your meta and og tags will be loaded from Laravel.